# Variable and pointer type casting warnings

Tags: c

I recently updated to a new compiler for a microcontroller and this new compiler is giving me the following warnings (see image). Old compiler it compiled without warnings.

[compileroutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGEZ6.jpg)

Preface, it has been many years since I wrote the program and I am not a programmer. A string is being sent to a i2c function to send to a lcd, the function in question is i2c_write_buff(const buffer_t, unsigned char); It doesn't like the first argument type which I show below and the function prototype.

```
// buffer pointer type.  The buffer is shared by an ISR and mainline code.
// the pointer to the buffer is also shared by an ISR and mainline code.
// Hence the double volatile qualification
typedef volatile unsigned char * volatile buffer_t;

//  write only, a string to the slave
int i2c_write_buff(const buffer_t, unsigned char);
```

The function that calls this function is shown below:

```
void lcd_string(const unsigned char *string)
{
    i2c_write_buff(string, lcd);
}
```

The LCD function was written separately for other types of microcontrollers and so doesn't know of the typedef buffer_t outside of this one program. I'm trying to figure out how to get these to match and make the compiler happy without having to add the typedef to the lcd library.

I tried different types that the compiler still didn't like.

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: C or C++? They're different languages, and their rules regarding casting are different.

Comment: please tag only the language you are using

Comment: Please post warnings as text into the question. `make the compiler happy without having to add the typedef to the lcd library.` I do not understand, you would include the same code and "have" the typedef. I do not understand. `was written separately for other types of microcontrollers and so doesn't know of the typedef` What does writing for other type of controller has to do with "knowing" of the typedef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get these to match

Remove the constness. The simplest would be to cast to the same type:

```
void lcd_string(const unsigned char *string) {
    i2c_write_buff((const buffer_t)string, lcd);
}
```

Once again, typedef pointers are confusing. `const buffer_t` is making the pointer constant, not pointed-to elements.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to figure out how to get it done!